# Oracle PL/SQL package not updating records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package, oracle12c

I have a table named INCOMING_MSG in an Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

```
INCOMING_MSG_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
CREATION_DATE            DATE           
CHANNEL                  VARCHAR2(50)   
MESSAGE                  VARCHAR2(1024) 
IP_ADDRESS               VARCHAR2(50)   
PARSED          NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
```

And I just create this package:

```
 procedure parseMsg 
  IS
        var1 VARCHAR(500);
        var2 VARCHAR(500);
        var3 VARCHAR(500);

        cursor c1 is
         SELECT incoming_msg_id
         FROM incoming_msg
            WHERE parsed = 0;


     begin

     FOR psd_rec in c1
     LOOP
        UPDATE incoming_msg SET PARSED=1;

    END LOOP;
  END;

end;
```

I got all the records running this query in my sqldeveloper:

```
SELECT incoming_msg_id
         FROM incoming_msg
            WHERE parsed = 0;
```

Then I run the procedure also from my sqldeveloper expecting that after the execution all the records will be with the value parsed = 1 but is not the case and I can't figure out why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `commit;` and `where` clause by id:

```
 begin

 FOR psd_rec in c1
 LOOP
    UPDATE incoming_msg i SET i.PARSED=1 where i.incoming_msg_id = psd_rec .incoming_msg_id;

END LOOP;
commit;
```

Comment: It is best to `commit` once, after exiting the loop.

Comment: Fixed by @APC note, if there are big number for records maybe 1 commit per then thousands of records is better

Comment: Not true. Such an approach can lead to ORA-01002 and ORA-01555 errors. Not to mention making it harder to recover if the program abends.